# Runtime progress status (like statusbar) in python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create simple progress status label for my Pyqt5 Python code and update it after every iteration of a loop in which a function does a bunch of stuff. The label I want to be updated is "status_label_counter". The below code only shows the part for creating labels and the exact place where I want to use the functionality I've mentioned.

```
    #initialisation code, etc...

    self.status_label_counter = QLabel()
    self.status_label_from = QLabel(' from: ')
    self.status_label_total = QLabel()
    status_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    status_hbox.addStretch()
    status_hbox.addWidget(self.status_label_counter)
    status_hbox.addWidget(self.status_label_from)
    status_hbox.addWidget(self.status_label_total)
    status_hbox.addStretch()

    #bunch of other code...

    def create_ics(self):
        counter = 0
        self.status_label_total.setText(str(len(self.groups)))
        for group in self.groups:
            #does a bunch of stuff inside
            group_manager.create_calendar_for(self.rows, group, self.term)
            counter += 1
            #for console output
            print('iteration: ', counter)
            #trying to update status counter
            self.status_label_counter.setText(str(counter))
```

The problem is that I only see the update of both labels when the loop is done with the nested function. When I click a button that calls for "create_ics" function window becomes inactive for about 5 seconds, I see logs on console with count of iterations, but nothing happens in view.

Comment: try QApplication.processEvents() inside of loop

Comment: I would also recommend using QThread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view (Qt) is locked in your main thread and never gets its chance to process its event loop and thus redraw itself. If you really want to do it this way, call:

```
self.status_label_counter.repaint()
```

After you set the text (and if you have some complex layout measuring call `QApplication.processEvents()` instead).

However, much better option would be to run your `create_ics()` function in a separate thread leaving your main thread to deal with the view and Qt's event processing. You can do it either through standard Python's [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module, or using Qt's own QThread: https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/ .

Comment: I used QApplication.processEvents(), and it worked, although the time of processing almost doubled, I see that it will work in this particular case because it's a matter of few seconds, but I'll also try threading, because if the number of items was not ~200 like it is now, but ~5000 it would actually matter. Thanks!

Comment: The processing time will, of course, increase - you're initializing Qt's event loop checkup on each call even tho it's not really needed, that's why threads are useful - Qt's event loop has its own schedule and it will update itself periodically, but in your case it gets stuck in your loop. When you separate your processing to another thread there will be nothing blocking Qt from updating. You can speed up your processing a bit without threading, too, just add a condition when should Qt process events, e.g.: `if not counter % 1000: QApplication.processEvents()`